# Difference between "antworten" and "beantworten"

Tags: difference, verb

Is there any difference between "antworten" and "beantworten"? In which situations should I use one and in which another?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

*Ich antworte **auf** etwas* (I reply **to** something), but *Ich beantworte etwas* (I answer something).

> Ich antworte auf Deinen Brief (I reply to your letter)
>   Ich beantworte Deine Frage (I answer your question)

In German, both is used equivalently, but you need to make sure to use the correct form (see the **auf** above).

Comment: In retrospect, I noticed that *beantworten* is close to *answer*. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: It puzzles me the fact that you wrote "Deine" with a capital "D". It is not a Sie-form as you should have used Ihren instead. So why?

Comment: @usr128787 Writing "Du, Dich, Dein, etc." or "Sie, Ihre, etc." with capital letters in letters is actually a form of polite salutation. While I think that today you don't need to do this anymore, it used to be a rule. Many people keep doing this even after the spelling reform. The question why I wrote "Du" instead of "Ihren" - well, I assumed this was a personal letter to a person I know. In a business letter you'd of course have used "Ihren".

Answer (score 39):

Just to add a little further detail and perhaps simplify the other fine answers, think of it this way:

"Antworten" is an intransitive verb, not performing direct action upon something and thus needing help to transfer the action either by using an auxiliary word followed by the Accusative case or else simply the Dative case without the auxiliary word.

"Beantworten" is a transitive verb, performing direct action upon something by using the Accusative case with no need of further help from an auxiliary word.

"Be-" is a common prefix to change an intransitive verb into a transitive one.

Comment: Nice answer. I like the analytical insight.

Comment: _Beantworten_ does not take dative, right?

Comment: @Alexey  It can, I suppose, but remember that **_beantworten_ is a transitive verb**, so it must always take a direct object, which, of course, is in accusative case.  Whether or not you choose to add an indirect object (a dative component) is up to you, but I think the construct would be really awkward.  Z.B.: Without dative component: _Beantworten die Frage_ (Answer the question.)  And with: _Beantworten mir die Frage_ (Answer me the question ... who talks like this?)  More commonly you'd say, "Answer the question for me."  (_Beantworten für mich die Frage._)

Comment: @Alexey  So, yeah, I think you're right, Alexey, _beantworten_ doesn't naturally take a dative or indirect object.  To confirm the transivity of a verb, I often use WordReference.  [**Here is its entry for _beantworten_.**](https://www.wordreference.com/deen/beantworten).  The other contributions to this this thread may help you as well.

Comment: Thanks! Word Reference looks very helpful:

_Peter beantwortete die Frage **der Lehrerin**._

So instead of saying **to whom** we answer, we say **whose** was the question. That clarifies everything.

Answer (score 20):

If you reply **to a question** or answer **someone** then you go with *antworten* which means *to respond*, *to be responsive*. If you answer **a question** or **a request** then you go with *beantworten* which means *to give an answer*. Additionally if you response to a letter you also use *beantworten* which now means *to give a written response*.

In almost most cases you can replace *beantworten* with *antworten auf*, i.e. when leaving out the prefix *be* you have to use the preposition *auf*.

> Ich beantworte seine Frage nicht. - Ich antworte auf seine Frage nicht.
>
> Er beantwortet jeden Brief. - Er antwortet auf jeden Brief.
>
> Der Lehrer antwortet dem Schüler mit anschaulichen Beispielen.

Note that *beantworten* carries the connotation of fully or, at the very least, sufficiently answering the question, *antworten auf* only suggest that you reply but this response may not be satisfying.

> Ich habe auf deine Frage geantwortet. Ist diese damit beantwortet?
> [=I replied to your question. Is this question answered?]

[Thorsten Dittmar's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/5592/1224) made me aware of something I just missed. English *reply to something* is the equivalent to German *auf etwas antworten* while English *answer something* is the equivalent to German *etwas beantworten*.

---

In German:

Man kann **auf eine Frage** *antworten* oder **jemandem** *antworten* [=reagieren, erwidern], aber **eine Frage** oder **eine Anfrage** *beantworten* [=Antwort geben]. Außerdem kann man auch **einen Brief** *beantworten* [=schriftliche Reaktion abgeben].

Man kann nahezu immer *beantworten* durch *antworten auf* ersetzen, verändert dadurch aber leicht die Aussage. *Beantworten* bedeutet, dass die Frage vollständig oder zumindest ausreichend beantwortet wurde, *antworten* sagt ausschließlich aus, dass auf die Frage reagiert wurde, aber die Frage ist möglicherweise noch nicht zufriedenstellend beantwortet.

Answer (score 11):

Let's try and get beyond a single example and understand the structure of how German words are formed.

The German prefix *be-* is one of several prefixes that turn another word - often an intransitive verb - into a transitive verb. The only reason this particular prefix is tricky for English speakers is that English has mostly lost it and now does the same thing without any prefix. Though there are still plenty of English words in which the prefix has survived - some of them very antiquated. Some random examples from [this list](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be-#Prefix):

- To *bewrap* an object means to *wrap* a material *around* the object. A typical use is when the object that is bewrapped is more relevant than the material that is wrapped around it.
- To *bewrite* an incident means to *write* a report *about* the incident. A typical use is when the incident that is bewritten is more relevant than the report that is written about it.
- To *beclothe* a person means to fit *clothes* around the person. This transitive verb is derived from a noun. Modern English does these derivations without the prefix.
- To *behead* a person means to take the person's *head* away. Again derived from a noun. For this particular shade of meaning, German uses a different prefix - *ent-* - though for this particular verb it goes without any prefix.
- To *bereave* a man of his fortune means to *reave* his fortune *from* him. A typical use is to mention the bereft man but not the fortune that was reaved. The verb seems to be held alive primarily by the participle *bereft*.
- For an adult to *befriend* a child means that the adult makes himself or herself a *friend* of the child.

(I have used specific terms such as "object" or "material" - not to restrict the definitions in their applications, but to make the references perfectly clear.)

Some parallel prefixes with different shades of meaning are still alive in English. You can use them to make up new verbs on the spot, though in many cases you would only want to do it for comic effect:

- What has been drunk cannot be undrunk. What has been sung or spoken cannot be unsung or unspoken, etc. Note that whereas *drink, sing, speak* can all be used either transitively (with a direct object) or without one, *undrink, unsing, unspeak* can only be used transitively. It should be clear what it would mean to unglass a drinker or to unhandkerchief a rheumy person.
- If you whelm someone too much with some unmentioned goodness, you overwhelm them. If you burden someone too much, or put too much burden on them, you overburden them. If you provide them with too much joy, you overjoy them and they become overjoyed. Everybody can guess what it would mean to overparrot a bird collector.
- If you put someone on a list, you enlist them. Before some consonants, the prefix becomes *em-* for phonetic reasons: If you give a person the power to do something, you empower them. It is clear what it would mean for Lego to embrick a personality. It is equally clear that if Montrésor, the hero of Poe's *The Cask of Amontillado*, does the same it probably amounts to en-graving the person - with *en-graving* an easily discernible pun. This prefix, like *be-*, is relatively neutral in meaning and therefore isn't normally used with verbs nowadays.
- Like *be-*, the English prefixes *for* and *fore* (corresponding to German *für-* and *vor-*, which also tend to be conflated) are no longer productive.

*Re-*, a loan prefix from Romance languages, could be added to this list. However, when you apply it to an intransitive verb you can still use the result without a direct object. This is why it's not a very good example.
(Nowadays you can also use the other productive prefixes to construct intransitive verbs. For example the infamous *overexaggerate* can be used intransitively. But this is a relatively recent phenomenon.)

---

Now let's apply the theory to *(be)antworten*. The basic word is the noun *Antwort*, which translates to the English noun *answer* and can be analysed roughly, but quite obviously and logically, as *anti-word*, i.e. *opposite word*. In German, the noun can be turned into an intransitive verb just by adding the appropriate ending, or into a transitive verb by also adding the prefix *be-*:

- Ich antworte (auf einen Brief). I reply (to a letter).
- Ich beantworte einen Brief. I answer a letter.

In the first example I used *reply*, a synonym of *answer* that can only be used intransitively. There is no English synonym of *answer* that can only be used transitively, but removing *einen Brief* from the second example would make the German sentence ungrammatical. For some other German verbs there are full English analogues:

- Ich arbeite (an einem Brief). I am working (on a letter).
- Ich bearbeite einen Brief. I am processing a letter.

Answer (score 8):

The other answers do almost cover it all... but some is missing so here is my try:

**beantworten** is always done to the question.

> Ich beantworte deine Frage.

You may or may not add the person. The translation that is closest in grammar to that is **to answer**.

> I answer your question.

Note however, that beantworten NEEDS an object. So the following wouldn't work.

> Answer me!
>
> <del>Beantworte mir!</del>

**Antworten** itself without **auf** cannot be done to the question (it is intransitive). Thus, the closest translation grammar-wise is **to respond**.

> Answer me! / Respond!
>
> Antworte mir!

Now, others have pointed out **antworten auf.** This is correct but there is a difference between **antworten auf** and **beantworten** in that the former is really just a response, while the latter implies that it is complete and the matter is settled. If I **beantworte** a question, it is answered. The question is no more. If I **antworte auf** a question, my answer can ambiguous, incomplete or even a counter question. It is really more a response than it is an actual answer.

For those who are interested: I have discussed this very question [in my blog](http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2012/09/09/antworten-beantworten-difference/) in more detail.

Answer (score 4):

The distinction between "Er beantwortete meine Frage" and "Er antwortete auf meine Frage" is actually much the same as that between "He answered my question" and "He replied to my question". The former implies that the answer dealt satisfactorily with the question, whereas the latter doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the semantic differences, I can't really do better than what has already been posted, but as a student of the German language, I find it immensely helpful to look at frequencies because I don't have time to learn 10 different ways to say one thing.  Before I commit to studying a word or phrase, I usually take the time to find out if it is the most common way of saying something before proceeding, especially when I find the semantic differences to be very small.  In the case of *antworten* and *beantworten,* I find it a very interesting case because frequencies of the infinitive do not match frequencies of these two words in context.  At least not as found with the Google Ngram.  Let me show you what I mean.  Here are frequencies of these two words in the infinitive:

[image]

However, if I put these two words in context (to include adding an object), you will see that this changes:

[image]

This difference is even more pronounced when using third person singular (and second person plural informal):

[image]

And even more interesting than that is this:

[image]

No n-grams are found at all for *antwortest auf die Frage*!

You can proceed as you like, but for me, for so many reasons (e.g., brevity, frequency, simplicity), I am much more likely to try to put into practice this phrase using some form of *beantworten* and leave it at that *if I am referring to a question*.  Note how all of this changes if you change "question" to "message."  (I opted for message over your example "letter" because letters are becoming a thing of the past in this age of technology.  When was the last time anyone sent or answered a "letter"?  But we read, answer, and send messages every day.)

[image]

Results were similar when comparing first person singular.  As with the previous example, no n-grams were found with *antworten* in this context in second person singular.

This reversal made me even more curious than ever, so I was compelled to try it with your original example — the letter.  Well, results were a lot closer, but forms of *beantworten* came out ahead.

Overall, despite the Nachricht examples, it still looks as if *beantworten* has a slight edge in terms of frequency.  Reverso backs this up.

[image]

Now why would this be?  I have no idea, but I think [this answer from Oliver](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/34442/20715) lends a clue.  In it, Oliver writes:

> The distinction between "Er beantwortete meine Frage" and "Er antwortete auf meine Frage" is actually much the same as that between "He answered my question" and "He replied to my question".

And if we compare this to English, are we more likely to answer questions and reply to messages and letters?  I think that answer is "yes":

[image]
*To enlarge image, open the page in Chrome, right click the image, and open it in a new tab.*

Comment: "as a student of the German language [...] I don't have time to learn 10 different ways to say one thing" What is your goal in learning German?

Comment: @infinitezero Well, the ultimate goal for me WRT any foreign language I'm learning is to get so good that I could translate, interpret, or be, in some other capacity, useful, to someone or something, for having taken the time and effort to study the language to a level of that proficiency. At such a level, I _would_ need to know, perhaps 10 different ways to say something, but in the beginning, I just want to learn the basics and learn them well. Z.B., in the beginning, it's sufficient to learn just one word for "dog."  Down the road, I can learn Dackel, Dalmatiner,  Deutsche Schäferhund, etc.